# How to set a radiobutton active in jQuery radiobutton group

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am trying to set a radiobutton active with the standart jQuery function like in this demo if you do a onclick event.

http://jqueryui.com/button/#radio

I wanna do the same that onclick does but not on click, i wanna do this in a function that is called.

Tried this but it is not working right:

```
function checkradio() {
    $("#labelRADIOVU").button("enable");
    $('#RADIOVU').prop('checked', true);
    //alert($("input[name='']:checked").val())
    document.getElementById("labelRADIOVU").style.color = "white";
    document.getElementById("labelRADIOVU").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    //document.getElementById("RADIOVU").checked = true;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger the click on radio

```
 $('#RADIOVU').trigger('click')
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/nZLeU/

Comment: Thanks a lot, thats the way it works!!! Sometimes you dont net to know all.. its enought to know an alternative ;-)